# Why does git merge origin/master not generate a commit message?

Tags: git

As I know that the `git pull origin master` is kinda *alias* of `git fetch origin` followed with `git merge origin/master`. However, when using `git merge` command for merging a change from other branch to master, there is usually an automatically generated *commit message*.

Question: why does `git merge origin/master` not generate a merge commit message automatically like in the usual case?

Comment: Side note: **do not** run `git pull origin/master` unless `master` is the currently checked out branch. You will get undesired results otherwise.

Comment: An even better advice is to avoid `git pull` completely. Use `git fetch` to update your local repository with the information about what changed on the remote repository, use a Git GUI program to inspect the changes and the status of the branches then use either `git merge` or `git rebase` to update your local branches. Make sure you don't have uncommitted local changes when you run commands that modify the local branches (`git merge`, `git rebase`, `git switch` etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [`git-pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---ff) documentation:

> ```
> --ff
> --no-ff
> --ff-only
> ```
>
> Specifies how a merge is handled when the merged-in history is already a descendant of the current history. `--ff` is the default
> unless merging an annotated (and possibly signed) tag that is not
> stored in its natural place in the `refs/tags/` hierarchy, in which case
> `--no-ff` is assumed.

`--ff` is used as default, which resolves the merge as a fast-forward if possible, and creates a merge commit when not possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. True, it is mentioned `with --ff, when possible resolve the merge as a fast-forward (only update the branch pointer to match the merged branch; do not create a merge commit).`